# Optitrack Motion Capture system and robot localization in Nav2 stack

Tags: navigation, ros2, turtlebot2, turtlebot, mocap-optitrack

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm looking for some tutorials, documentation, code/configuration snippets,
example projects and other sources with information on how I can incorporate
an external Motion Capture System (Optitrack + Motive 3.0.1 cameras) as
a really reliable (99% of time) localization source in a Nav2-based Turtlebot 2 motion control
(upgraded to ROS 2 Galactic at the moment).

For connection of Motive and ROS2 I am using this project:

- https://github.com/MOCAP4ROS2-Project/mocap4ros2_optitrack

I can get the location of the markers through the `/markers` topic as in this [Getting Started tutorial](https://mocap4ros2-project.github.io/),
but I'm not sure how to combine this information in the robot's Nav2 stack.

Some mentions of it [are here](https://navigation.ros.org/concepts/index.html?highlight=motion%20capture#standards) and [(maybe) here](https://navigation.ros.org/setup_guides/odom/setup_odom.html#robot-localization-demo) (as in a fused and locally accurate smooth odometry information from the data provided by `N` odometry sensor inputs).

[This tutorial](https://automaticaddison.com/sensor-fusion-using-the-robot-localization-package-ros-2/) is a bit hard to follow, but maybe it could be the base of a solution for MoCap-supported localization?

I think it should be somethink similar to [this Q&A](https://answers.ros.org/question/228022/robot_localization-with-mocap-data-as-alternative-to-gpsnavsatfix/), [this](https://kapernikov.com/the-ros-robot_localization-package/) or [this "Integrating GPS Data" in `robot_localization`](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/integrating_gps.html), but for ROS2. I would like some guidance here, though.

Other related things I found:

- https://answers.ros.org/question/276731/robot_localization-with-odometryimugps/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/223152/robot_localization-as-simple-filter-without-fusion/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/310443/using-vicon-as-groundtruth-in-robot-localization/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/280831/specifics-of-sensor-fusion-algorithm-of-robot_localization-package/
- https://answers.ros.org/question/351790/no-odometryfiltered-output-from-robot_localization/

Please advise, any hints are welcome!

Best

Łukasz Janiec

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/406883/optitrack-motion-capture-system-and-robot-localization-in-nav2-stack/) by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3064 on 2022-09-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-10-08**:
Is it generating pose or just x,y,z location? Approximately how often does this system generate a current pose estimate? What do you think the accuracy is?

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.ros.org/users/63587/ljaniec/) on 2022-10-10**:
It uses [this `RigidBody.msg`](https://github.com/MOCAP4ROS2-Project/mocap_msgs/blob/m), that's it:

```
std_msgs/Header header

uint32 frame_number
string rigid_body_name
Marker[] markers
geometry_msgs/Pose pose
```

Optitrack gave me in a rosbag of 20 s 2350 frames, so it is probably ~100-120 Hz? Correct me if I am wrong. For my supervisor controller for multiple AMRs I need a current pose estimate on the level around 10-20 Hz. I am not sure how often should it be sent in Nav2 `robot_localization`. After calibration, Motive 3 shows an error of 0.5 mm per marker, I'm not sure how strongly this will correlate to the robot's overall localization error (each robot has 4 markers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With a high quality global localization like you describe, you don't really need standard odometry techniques (or a kalman filter.) You could just use the pose directly. The TF tree could look like this: `map -> optitrack -> base_link`, where `map->optitrack` is a static transform.

You could add odometry to the above TF tree, but setting that up is more complicated. As with AMCL, you'd then use the optitrack pose to correct the drift in the odometry.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2022-10-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2022-10-11**:
AMCL and other global localizer‘s provide the map to odometry frame transformation. So really, all you need to do here is provide the same thing. If you have globally accurate localization from an external source, you may use that. So just don’t launch a AMCL and create a note which publishes that transform using your motion capture system data. Depending on the quality of the data, it may be advantageous to use a kalmon filter, so RL can provide that. But if filtering is not required, that should be sufficient. But conveniently RL does provide that transformation automatically when setup to provide that data.